# Online tool to calculate IP mask

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I know there are so many tools to calculate a network range starting from an IP and its mask (192.168.1.0/24) but do you know an online tool to calculate the mask starting from first and last IP available?

For example I have these IPs and nothing more: 79.0.0.0 - 79.7.255.255
How can I calculate the mask? (it's /13 in this case).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for:

[Mask calculator](http://bonomo.info/coyote/ip-calculator.php)

*Fll in the IP range or block and the calculator will display the network IP in CIDR notation, usable IPs, IP broadcast address, network mask, and wildcard mask.*